# How to break a string with no spaces into words

Tags: java, string

If I have a string `h   ell##!omynam493eisj2ohn` ( I've removed all whitespaces, digits, punctuation and etc... using regex) to get: `hellomynameisjohn`

Now what I want to do is for every `n` character - so say the minimum length of a word is `4`, so for every `4` characters I want to add in a space and increment count. This is what I got up to so far.

```
    public static int countWords(String original, int minLength){

    original = original.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","").replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
    System.out.println(original);

    System.out.println(original.length());

    int count = 0;

    return count;
}
```

4 characters = 1 word. Therefore, for every 4 characters add in a space and increment the count by 1. I'm not sure on how I can convert this logic into code.  I was thinking about using a for-loop but this is how far I got.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<original.length; i++){

    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a string builder above the loop, and if `i` is divisible by 4, add a space, else just add the character at index  `i + wordCount`

Comment: Or just split every 4, then join with spaces.

Comment: Use substring: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Comment: @clinical I can get away with original.substring(0,minLength-1) for to create one word, but how can use this in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your method just wants to count how many words are inside with minLength?

```
 public static int countWords(String original, int minLength){

    original = original.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","").replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
    System.out.println(original);

    System.out.println(original.length());

    int count = (original.length()+minLength-1) / minLength;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. What I implemented was

Comment: int count = original.length() / minLength;          so for ever n character equals one word. Now I just have the issue being when n is negative number.